# iCheck Plug in & Knockout Js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, icheck

I need some help to check a checkbox on page load using knockout & icheck plug in.

I have created a custom binding in order to listen to 'ifChecked' method of check but it's not working.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="access-user-information" name="edit_existing_user" data-bind = "iCheck: { checked: selectedUser() && selectedUser().edit_existing_user==1}">
```

Knockout Code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {     
                init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

                    $(element).iCheck({
                        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red'
                    });

                    $(element).on('ifChecked', function (event) {
                        var observable = valueAccessor();
                        observable.checked(true); 
                    });
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                }
            };
```

Comment: Note what is the value of checked property. Certainly not an observable, but a boolean: true/false. Therefore, `observable.checked(true); ` will never work

Comment: What should be the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Some changes:

- Listen for a change at the checkbox ('ifToggled' event)
- The observable of a checkbox should be a boolean, so set the value according to the checkbox state (true/false). I used the jQuery .is(':checked') for that.
- Set the initial state in the "update" function.

The code for the binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

    $(element).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-red'
    });

    $(element).on('ifToggled', function(event) {
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable($(element).is(':checked'));
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    observable($(element).is(':checked'));
  }
};
```

Here a little [jsbin](http://codepen.io/atitsbest/pen/ygapEj) to test it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is `enabled`, and you can give it a new value by tapping it, it has to be a `ko.computed` with a `read` and `write` method.

When you select the current user, you want it to automatically be checked. This is the `read` part:

```
this.isEditingCurrentUser = ko.computed(function() {
  return this.selectedUser() && 
         this.selectedUser().edit_existing_user === 1;
}, this);
```

You should recognise this expression: it's what you used as your data-bind. Having a `ko.computed` in your viewmodel is very similar to using expressions in data-binds.

Now, there's a problem when you want to override this value with `true` or `false`: knockout can't decide for you how to *reverse* the logic. This, you have to specify. It'll look like this:

```
this.isEditingCurrentUser = ko.computed({
  read: function() { /* the expression above */ },
  write: function(newValue) { /* How to handle a user input override */ }
});
```

I show how this works in the example below. I've left out the custom binding since the real logic problem needs to be solved first:

```js
var VM = function() {
  var currentUserId = 1;
  
  this.users = [
    { id: 1, name: "User 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "User 2" },
    { id: 3, name: "User 3" },
  ];
    
  this.selectedUser = ko.observable(2);
  this.editCurrent = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return this.selectedUser() &&
             this.selectedUser().id === currentUserId;
    }.bind(this),
    write: function(val) {
      var newUser = val
        ? this.users.find(function(user) {
            return user.id === currentUserId;
          })
        : null;
    
      this.selectedUser(newUser);
    }.bind(this)
  }, this);
};
    
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: users, value: selectedUser, optionsCaption: 'Select a user', optionsText: 'name'"></select>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: editCurrent">
  Edit current user
</div>
```